$E[X\mid XY]$ where $(X,Y)$ is any coordinate uniformly selected from the unit square $[0,1]^2$
I am trying to solve this problem but was not sure if I am right.
Problem: Find $E[X\mid XY]$ where $(X,Y)$ is any coordinate uniformly selected from the unit square $[0,1]^2$
What I have tried: Let $Z=XY$ then
\begin{align}
& P(X \leq x \mid Z=z) \\[8pt]
= {} & 1 - \int^1_z \int^1_{z/x} \, dy \, dx \\[8pt]
= {} & 1-z+z\ln(z), \qquad 0<z<1.
\end{align}
I'm stuck here because the I don't know how to get the PDF of $X\mid Z=z$ so that I could continue to calculate $E[X\mid Z=z]$. What did I do wrong? Is there any other correct way? (Maybe I should use double expectation theorem?)

I suspect your expression for $P(X \leq x \mid Z=z)$ is wrong.  If it were correct, you could take the derivative with respect to $x$ to get the conditional pdf, at least when $z \le x \le 1$.

One simple way: observe that expectations can be found by integrating the survival function and compute that function, for arbitrary $0\lt t\lt 1$ and $0\le x\le 1.$  (Pay attention to the special case $0\le x \lt t.$) This avoids computing the PDF altogether and spares you one integration.  For intuition about conditional probabilities of zero-probability events see the figures at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/584907/919.

@whuber I get your point.  But to be clear, how one can "avoid computing the (conditional) pdf" since we still need to evaluate the quantity $P(X > x \mid XY = z)$ (i.e., the conditional survival function)?

@Zhanxiong I don't follow you--that's a survival function, not a PDF.  One doesn't need the compute the conditional PDF to find its survival function.

@whuber How? Can you spell out the details? Be mindful this is conditional survival function, not the unconditional one.

@Zhanxiong The conditional survival function is unity for $x\le t,$ zero for $x\gt 1,$ and and for $0\lt t\le x\le 1$ it is $$\Pr(X\ge x\mid XY = t) = \frac{\int_x^1 \frac{\mathrm dt}{x}\mathrm dx}{\int_t^1 \frac{\mathrm dt}{x}\mathrm dx} =  \frac{\log x}{\log t}.$$ Integrating this over $[0,\infty)$ gives the solution.

@whuber what does the expression "$\int_t^1 \frac{dt}{x}{dx}$" mean? -- It looks like a double integral but how "$dx$" gets disappeared?

@Zhanxiong It's a differential. The integral is over $x$ while the $\mathrm dt$ terms cancel.  As I indicated in my original comment, this directly (and easily) yields the correct answer.  The origin of this expression is explained in the second link I gave in my first comment.

In general, for two random variables $\xi, \zeta$ with joint density $f(x, z)$, the conditional density of $\xi$ given $\zeta = z$ is given by
\begin{align}
g(x|z) = \frac{f(x, z)}{\int_\mathbb{R} f(t, z)dt}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.  \tag{1}
\end{align}
So the key step of solving this problem is to determine the joint distribution of $(X, Z)$ (where $Z = XY$ as you noted).  By considering the bijective $\xi = X, \zeta = XY$ with Jacobian determinant $\xi^{-1}$, it can be shown that the joint density of $(X, Z)$ is
\begin{align}
f(x, z) = \begin{cases}
x^{-1} & (x, z) \in \{(u, v): 0 \leq u \leq 1, 0 \leq v \leq u\}, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases} \tag{2}
\end{align}
The 3D surface plot of the joint density $f$ is shown as follows:

It then follows by $(1)$ and $(2)$ for $0 < z < 1$ that
\begin{align}
g(x|z) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^{-1}}{\int_z^1 t^{-1}dt} = -\frac{1}{x\log z}& z \leq x \leq 1, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
The curve of $g(x|z)$ is shown as follows:

Hence
\begin{align}
E[X|Z = z] = \int_z^1 xg(x|z)dx = -\int_z^1 \frac{1}{\log z}dx = 
-\frac{1 - z}{\log z}.
\end{align}
In terms of standard conditional expectation notation, this is
\begin{align}
E[X|XY] = -\frac{1 - XY}{\log(XY)}.  
\end{align}

I suspect your expression for $P(X \leq x \mid Z=z)$ may be wrong. If it were correct, you could take the derivative with respect to $x$ to get the conditional pdf, at least when $z \le x \le 1$. The conditional expectation would then be easy.
I think $P(X \leq x \mid Z=z) = \dfrac{\int\limits_{x'=z}^x \frac1{x'}\, dx'}{\int\limits_{x'=z}^1 \frac1{x'}\, dx'} = \dfrac{\log(x)-\log(z)}{0-\log(z)} = 1-\dfrac{\log_e(x)}{\log_e(z)} $  when $z \le x \le 1$, and $0$ when $x \le z$, and $1$ when $x\ge 1$.
This suggests $f_{X \mid Z=z}(x)= \dfrac{1}{-x\, \log_e(z)}$ when $z \le x \le 1$, and $0$ otherwise.
So $\mathbb E[ X \mid Z=z ]= \int\limits_{x=z}^1 x\dfrac{1}{-x\, \log_e(z)} \, dx = \dfrac{1-z}{-\log_e(z)}$ when $0 < z < 1$.
As check using R:
set.seed(2024)
z <- 0.6
pm <- 0.001
cases <- 10^7
X <- runif(cases)
Y <- runif(cases)
Z <- X * Y
ok <- z-pm < Z & Z < z+pm 
mean(X[ok])
# 0.7828329
(1-z) / (-log(z))
# 0.7830461

which seems close after allowing for simulation noise
